# Join tables based on closest text match in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, match, closest

I'm using Microsoft Access. I'm still quite new to SQL (sorry if my current approach looks too simple), and I'm stuck on trying to join two tables that have different column names, in which one table has the full printer models' names, whereas the other table just has part of the printer's model name.

Here is some sample data

TableA:
**Model**
MS811DN LASER PRINTER
MS811D**T**N LASER PRINTER
MS812 LASER PRINTER

TableB:
**Model**
MS811DTN
MS811DN
MS81 (in which anything after MS81 can represent anything besides MS811DTN or MS811DN)

I've tried using the following in the FROM Statement:
FROM
TableA 
LEFT JOIN Table B
ON TableA.Model LIKE TableB.Model&'*'

but that returns duplicate results since it provides all the values that the models are "like"

What I'm looking to do is to return results that provide the closest match, such that 
Table A                                        Table B
MS811DN LASER PRINTER               links to        MS811DN
MS811D**T**N LASER PRINTER     links to        MS811DTN
MS812 LASER PRINTER            links to        MS81

Is there a way to just return results that are the closest match?

Comment: Is table A too big to be equipped with column which could be filled (possibly by some algorithm, then manually adjusted) by values corresponding to key from table B? This way you could convert closest match (which looks sometimes like guessing to me) to exact matches.

Comment: I have over 30,000 fields in Table A that need to be matched up (not sure if that's considered too big), but did you mean to equip Table A with another column into the Table prior to pulling the query? If so, I would like to avoid that step since I'm writing this query for others to just copy and paste when they pull a report. If that's not what you meant, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original select is fine. As you mention

```
select ... 
FROM TableA 
    LEFT JOIN Table B ON TableA.Model LIKE TableB.Model&'*'
```

Then we can introduce similarity value calculated field.

```
LEN(TableB.Model) - LEN(TableA.Model)
```

If it's 0 we found exact match.

Then you need to add

```
GROUP BY TableA.Model
```

and find a MIN(similarity) for each Model.

Then leave only records with the minimal similarity.

```
select *
FROM TableA INNER JOIN 
   (select TableA.Model, MIN(LEN(TableB.Model) - LEN(TableA.Model)) as minSim
    FROM TableA 
        LEFT JOIN Table B ON TableA.Model LIKE TableB.Model&'*'
    GROUP BY TableA.Model) sub ON TableA.Model=sub.Model
    LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.Model LIKE TableB.Model&'*' 
                    and sub.minSim=LEN(TableB.Model) - LEN(TableA.Model)
```

I am not familiar with Access so syntax could be wrong. Just to show the idea

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response! I tried using your suggestion but for some reason the last line "and sub.minSim=LEN(TableB.Model) - LEN(TableA.Model)" doesn't allow it to run. An error message saying "JOIN expression not supported" keeps popping up, and when I take that statement out, it works again. Any idea what can be done to solve this?

Comment: sub.minSim=(LEN(TableB.Model) - LEN(TableA.Model)) what about the brackets? I am not an expert in MS Access to provide exact syntax. You need to store the similarity and leave only ones with minimal distance

Comment: Microsoft Access's syntax is so hard to look at compared to other sql platforms. The brackets didn't seem to work either, but it worked when I put the last line in the WHERE statement at the end. Is there a reason why that would be a bad choice?

Comment: I would say it's fine to move the condition to WHERE section. Try also to play with NULLs when TableB does not have appropriate model